# Return node names and Text as STring with XPath

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath

I try to convert a Html-page to an ecs-Object. For this I'm using partweise XPath. (I'm coding in Java)
The Only problem is, that I want the XPath to return all node names and text as a String. It's a little bit hard to explain so, heres an example:

HTML-Document:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Derp</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>nonsense&lt;IOText&gt;</div>
    <a href="http://google.de/">It's Google!</a>
</body>
```

Now i want to execute the following XPath:

```
/html
```

And want the result look like this:

```
 <head>
    <title>Derp</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>nonsense&lt;IOText&gt;</div>
    <a href="http://google.de/">It's Google!</a>
</body>
```

Is there such an function?

Comment: Well till now I just searched for a solution... But I couldn't find one or think of one :/ I tried some functions like text() (returns null, whats reasonable) and some other XPath functions, whioch are just throwing errors, because Java doesn't know them (name() or local-name())

Comment: so you just want to remove `<html>`?

Comment: No, I want the Text inside the Tags, which im Requesting with XPath. Another example: If I would execute /html/head it should return <title>Derp</title>

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Java question, it's an XSLT question.  I believe this will do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/html/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have never found evidence of your claim that Java's XPath class doesn't handle XSLT functions.  Can you provide an XSL stylesheet which is known to work with other XSLT tools but not with Java's XPath?